# when is ん pronounced as "m"?

Tags: pronunciation

I've been initially told that ん is always pronounced like the **n** in pi**n**k. But I've been looking at this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Japanese#cite_note-stop-2

And it is saying that the ん in words like せ**ん**ぱい is pronounced as **m** as in **m**uch.

So is there any way to know if I should pronounce ん as **n** or **m** in a word?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ん assimilates to the consonantal sounds that follow.  If it is followed by 't' or 'd', then it is pronounced like an 'n'.  If it is followed by 'p' or 'b', it is pronounced like 'm'.  If followed by 'k' or 'g', then like 'ng' from 'sing'.

If ん is not followed by a consonant, then there isn't really a true English equivalent; it's more or less its own syllabic 'n'.

But technically, ん is never quite pronounced as in English since it always constitutes a mora.  So, in the example you gave せんぱい consists of four beats, and is pronounced more like 'se.mm.pa.i' (4 moras) than 'sem.pai' (2 syllables).

Comment: The case when its not followed by a consonant, as in すみません or わかりません? My hearing might be inaccurate, but I tend to hear these words being pronounced with an 'm' sound.

Comment: @FelipeMüller To pronounce 'm' in English, we press our lips together.  At the end of a word, like the two you provided, the lips do not need to come together.

Comment: @FelipeMüller That sound is actually made with your uvula; if you have difficulty doing so, using the velum should be an approximate substitute.

Comment: Is there an IPA character for that? When I try to pronounce 'm' without pressing the lips I end up pronouncing the 'n' in pink.

Comment: @FelipeMüller However you try to pronounce it, the lips do not come together and the tongue never makes contact with the top of your mouth whether behind the teeth or the roof of the mouth or the back of the mouth.

Comment: Those conditions are met in the 'n' in pink, aren't they?

Comment: @FelipeMüller Technically in English, the 'n' in 'pink' is pronounced by the back of the tongue making contact with the back of the roof of the mouth.

Comment: That is true. I think I can sort of do this without touching the tongue in the roof of the mouth, but I'm not sure if I'm doing correctly.

Comment: @FelipeMüller The uvular nasal is [ɴ] in IPA.  The velar nasal is [ŋ] in IPA.

Comment: I found this video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iQnB8crvnk "[ ɴ ] voiced back dorsal uvular nasal stop"

Answer (score 0):

Followed by m,p and b ん sound is pronounced as "m"
Eg: さんぱ (sampo)
Followed by k and g sounds it is pronounced as "ng"
Eg: まんが (manga)